# How to access this in Jquery each

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, each

I am iterating over input elements using `.each()` and want to get `class` of each input element.

```
$("input").each(function(index,element){
 // Here I want to access class value of current input ie. element here (I guess) 
});
```

For example

HTML

```
<input name="name1" class="class1" value="input1">
<input name="name2" class="class2" value="input2">
```

I tried following selectors in `.each` but getting return as `undefined`

```
 1. alert($('this').attr['class']);  
 2. alert($(this).attr['class']);      
 3. alert(element.class);  // I can access name using element.name
 4. alert($(element).attr['class']);
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kGjr2/
How can I access respective `input` and its properties inside `.each()`?

Thanks!

---

Really amazed by the quantity and quality of answers and that to within a really short time. Just wondering which answer should I accept. Thanks you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use parenthesis instead of square brackets... you are calling functions:

```
$("input").each(function(index,element){
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
});
```

You can also select the elements by class:

```
$('.class1')...//do something to only the elements with the `class1` class
```

Here is an updated version of your JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kGjr2/1/

### Update

The reason you are getting `undefined` alerted at you is because square brackets are for accessing a property of an object/array. But since you are using the square brackets on a function you aren't going to find any property names that match `class`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will accept this after 4 mins. (SO constraints) :)

Answer (score 2):

The class of an element is stored in the `className` property, so use `this.className` or `element.className`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I was not aware of it.Where can i get list of all properties?

Answer (score 1):

You're close.

```
$(this).attr("class");
```